# How can I create rows without tableview and collection view in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have questions in interview.I don’t  have tableview and collection view in xcode. Then I want to create row dynamically like tableview. How can i do that ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

With `UIScrollView`, iterating through the amount of "cells" and adding them as subviews.

Note that some logic to reuse them as the user scroll would be necessary so you don't overflow the memory depending on the amount of "cells".

Additionally, you should discuss some delegate and datasource methods and possible alternatives to them.

Comment: Using a stack view inside the scroll view will also help with setting up constraints.

Comment: @pepsy can you explain more

Comment: What I meant is that by using Stack View’s ‘addArrangedSubview’ to add a cell, it will automatically set your cell’s top, bottom, left and right constraints. I can answer with an example later tonight.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you'll need is a `UIScrollView`, to be able to scroll through your cells. As it can be quite annoying to set up the constraints when adding sub-views to a scroll view, I'd use a vertical `UIStackView` to ease things up.

When calling a vertical stack view's `addArrangedSubview(view: UIView)`, it will automatically set up constraints for your subview to occupy the full width of the stack view, and position it right under the last view inside the stack view.

The view structure would look like this:

[image: view structure]

The scroll view's constraints would be those:

[image: scroll view constraints]

And the stack view's constraints would be those:

[image: stack view constraints]

You can also add other stack views inside the first one to create different sections. In the example below, the "main" stack view has a spacing of 5, while the stack views "section 0" and "section 1" have a spacing of 1.

[image: multiple sections]

Now, as Gustavo Vollbrecht said, if you happen to have many cells on your "table view", then you would need to implement some logic to reuse cells, to prevent memory overflows. But that would make this answer a lot more complicated, so I hope you won't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Rows are just views. If you don't use .xib just as UITableViewCell() or from .xib
as UINib(...). instantiate(...).